# sə'bɔ:dɪneɪt - səˈbɔːdɪnɪt - səˈbɔːdɪnət - səˈbɔːdnɪt - Which pronunciation is correct?

Tags: pronunciation

I think it's the first time I'm so confused and lost. 
Some years ago when I was studying English I learnt the word "subordinate" pronounced as **[səˈbɔːdnɪt]**.

Now I can see other three types of pronunciation **[sə'bɔ:dɪneɪt - səˈbɔːdɪnɪt - səˈbɔːdɪnət]** from different sources.

Would you help me to clarify which is correct?

Comment: Have you googled it? /səˈbɔːdɪneɪt/ is the pronunciation of 'subordinate' as a verb and /səˈbɔːdɪnət/ is its pronunciation as a noun and an adjective.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul, of course I have. That's why it's messed up now. There was nothing about verbs or adjectives. So do you want to say that the other two option are not correct?
For example here https://www.lexico.com/definition/subordinate it has the same pronunciation for adj., nouns and verbs.

Comment: Whether or not a particular pronunciation is correct, depends on the variety of English and the speaker.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul, thanks a lot!

Comment: What happened to the r? My Midwestern American definitely has an r there.

Comment: @Xanne the *r* is a [rhotic issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English), while the final syllable is more an question of part of speech.  [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subordinate) therefore gives four pronunciations

Comment: @Xanne, because this is a British pronunciation, not American.

Comment: English has different pronunciations for different words depending on the country and the region. Other languages are the same. You shouldn't be confused by this, because it's an essential nature of all human languages.